# Not exiting Javascript loop when using boolean

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to add to the loop so that the user is prompted if they would like to make another entry. If yes, loop again, if no, exit the loop.

I have tried using a boolean saying if they choose yes, the students = true, and the loop continues. A simplified version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>


    <script>
        
    //Declare Variable
    var students = true;
    var total;
    var message = "";
  
    //Process

    while(students = true){
        name = prompt("Enter the student name:");
        while(name == ""){
        name = prompt("Invalid entry, please enter the student name:");
          }

            students = (prompt("Add another student? Enter Y or N")).toUpperCase();
            while(students == "" || students != "Y" && students != "N"){
        students = prompt("Invalid entry, would you like to add another student? Enter Y or N:").toUpperCase();
          }
          if(students == "Y"){
            students = true;
          }
          else if(students == "N"){
            students = false;
          }   
          
            message+= "\nName: "+name+"\nMidterm grade: "+midterm+"\nFinal exam grade: "+final+"\nHomework grade: "+homework+"\nAttendance grade: "+attendance+"\nTotal points: "+total+"\nPercentage: "+percent+"\nLetter grade: "+letterGrade+"\n";
          
          }
        
          //Output
          if(students = false){
          alert("Student Grades"+message);
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `students = true` is assignment. Use `===` or `==` for equality. Just like you do further down in the code.

Comment: Bruh moment. Thx